# Showing the Bernstein Polynomial for f(x) = x^3 converges

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

We know $f(x) = x^3$. Now, I'm trying to show that $\mathbb{B}_n(f) \to f$.

I've shown this:
$$B_n(f; x) = x^3 + \frac{1}{n^2}x(1 - x)(1 + (3n - 2)x$$
So we have
$$\left| B_n(f) - f \right| = \left|x^3 + \frac{1}{n^2}x(1 - x)(1 + (3n - 2)x - x^3\right| = \frac{1}{n^2} \left|x(1 - x)(1 + (3n - 2)x\right|$$
from here I do not know what can I do.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You have it! What stops you to conclude?

Comment: Hint: what happens to the right-hand term of $B_n(f;x)$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Is $x$ inside a bounded set? If not, it does not seem that the convergence is uniform.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace I don't know how to show epsilon on the right side. Do I need to do this?

Comment: @William I don't know how to show epsilon on the right side. Do I need to do this?

Comment: @YgorArthur I do not have any information about bound for f and x

Comment: Then the convergence can not be uniform. Because for any $n$ you can find $x$ such that the right-hand side is as big as you want.

Comment: @YgorArthur It is uniform on any interval, this is a way to prove Stone-Weierstraß theorem

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace any bounded interval. That was my question, is $x$ in a bounded interval?

Comment: @YgorArthur no, $x$ is not even a set, but {x} is. also I meant segment not interval

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace I really don't get your point. The uniform convergence in this case depends on the domain of $f$, i.e., what is the set in which $x$ is varying in.